# Axios self signed certificate error even when supplying certificates

Tags: node.js, ssl, axios

I am using axios to connect to an internal server. The network admin has given me the root certificate chain to access the server, however axios still gives me an error when I supply them.

```
const certBundle = [
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/master.pem', 'ascii'),
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/root.pem', 'ascii')
];
const agent = new https.Agent({
    ca: certBundle
});
let response = await axios.post(req.body.request, {httpsAgent: agent});
```

Are the certificates actually being used by axios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this needs to be added to the global http agent.

```
const https = require('https');
https.globalAgent.options.ca = [
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/master.pem'),
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/root.pem')
];
```

After adding that, everything works and axios is accepting the traffic.